# Java, Calculate minutes in a year

Tags: java

Im writing a simple java project that will calculates and prints the number of minutes in a year. can you please guide me through. Thanks.

Comment: Where is the program you're writing ? Put in your question so one can help.

Comment: As already mentioned, could you show us the code you have so far? you will get much more help if you do that

Comment: Although such kinds of questions should not be asked, let me give you a hand. First of all, you need to calculate the number of minutes in day. You already know that one hour contains 60 minutes, and that one day contains 24 hours. Moving from this, you should calculate how many minutes are there in 1 week, in 1 month (4 weeks) and then calculate how many minutes there are in 1 year (month * 12) Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually I haven't anything yet as I dont know how to start this. so if someone could give me reference about this. thanks

Comment: @BeansLookOcampos sure you can have a [refference here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year)

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11242228/942391

Comment: This Question is too vague. Do you mean a generic year of 365 days of 24 hours long? Or do you want to consider Leap Year? Or do you want an accurate result that applies a particular time zone since days are *not* always 24-hours long in some places on some dates?

Answer (score 3):

60*24*365 = 525600 - Normal Year
60*24*366 = 527040 - Leap Year

End of topic.

Comment: What about accumulated leap seconds?!

Answer (score 3):

For Both normal as well as Leap year.

```
 public  int getMinutesFromYear(int year)
 {
  return ((year % 400) == 0) ? 366 * 24 * 60 : (year % 100 != 0 && year % 4 == 0) ? 366 * 24 * 60 : 365 * 24 * 60;
  }
```

Comment: Assumes days are always 24-hours long which is *not* true. An accurate account must apply time zone to adjust for anomalies such as a government deciding to change the offset-from-UTC as Turkey did in 2016 and Russia has done multiple times in recent years.

Answer (score -1):

```
  public class Example{
       public static void main(String[]args){
           System.out.println(365*24*60);
       }
    }
```